# How do I update definers to enable MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create a MySQL replica in Cloud SQL, Google's managed MySQL service. However I have the following error which won't allow me to start replication:

```
 "kind": "sql#externalSyncSettingErrorList",
  "errors": [
    {
      "kind": "sql#externalSyncSettingError",
      "type": "UNSUPPORTED_DEFINER",
      "detail": "Definer user root@localhost not supported. Please update host to '%'."
    }
  ]
```

The docs suggest this as the solution:

> Update the definer in the external databases, for example from
> root@localhost to root@%

I am quite new to MySQL and I don't know how to make this change. I have done some research and it seems definers are related to some action like `view`, `event`, or `routine` so I suppose the question becomes which actions do I need to update the definer for to enable replication?

I found the following snippet which I guess is something like what I will need:

```
  foreach view, event, trigger, routine as object
    foreach object with definer=old_user 
      ALTER object DEFINER=new_user
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are out of luck.  Furthermore, some significant changes were made in MySQL 8.0; what version are you using?

Comment: I have a few clusters, some with MySQL 5.7 and some with MySQL 8.0. This problem is only on those with MySQL 5.7. When you say out of luck what do you mean?